# dotnet core 3.1 json deserialization not working (System.Text.Json)

Tags: json, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

Using the System.Text.Json deserializer doesn't produce the expected results. There are no errors thrown, just a list without values....all object properties are null.

Here is a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QYrvy5

Here is the code in question. "data" is just a json string (see dotnet fiddle):

```
  products = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ProductCatalogProduct>>(data);
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code and check a property names in json and c# classes?

Comment: got it to work, 2 things: 1) POCO need parameterless constructors and 2.) added options to deserialer call (var options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };)

Comment: You can also solve it by adding `PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase` to `JsonSerializerOptions`